# Cross-Device Visitor Count in Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

This might be off-topic - I'm trying to weazel my way out by virtue of the fact that I'm asking about the visitorID in Adobe Analytics, which after all is set in the tracking code.....

In their [documentation for Cross-Device Visitor Identification](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/visit_example.html) in Adobe Analytics Adobe shows the following table:

[image]

I would like to understand why for servercall 12 and 13 the number of visits is shown as "9".

With the servercalls 1-8 the user is not authenticated and a visitorID is automatically assigned. In calls 9 and 10 he is authenticated and thus recognized as a new user with 1 visit.

With servercall 11 he visits from another device and a visitorID is automatically assigned, so this counts as a new user with one visit.

With the authentication at servercall 12 the same visitorID as in call 9/10 is assigned. It is my understanding that now the visits should be incremented starting from the number of visits after the first authentication (servercall 9), so this should be 2.

However the table says "9", as if Adobe proceeds counting from the un-authenicated visits in servercall 1-8.

Is this a problem with my understanding or with the documentation ? (I.e. will the visitorID from my backend system beat the automatically assigned ID and sum up only authenticated visits, or how else is the number of visits per visitorID calculated).

Comment: It's a typo. Welcome to Adobe documentation, where things are often typoed, misleading, unclear, or outright contradicted in other places.

Comment: It would be helpful if they at least allowed people to comment on the doc pages like they do for some of their other online docs (I posted a while back on ideas.omniture.com asking for this, FWIW)

Comment: Thank you (you might as well make this an answer and I'll accept, I trust your expertise when it comes to Adobe).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is correct in this case, but indirect, I can see why there is confusion, the overall content needs to be read as a whole https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/xdevice_visid.html, When originally authored this was part of a PDF guide and the over all example was more connected with the preceding texts.
It is not a simple topic unfortunately which does not help. But please do not disregard this as an erroneous example, it is how Adobe Analytics works.

In the first interaction Adobe Analytics knows who the visitor is and has authenticated before. This is not totally obvious, but is indicated by the following information "A visitor clicks on a link in a marketing e-mail" and by the preceding texts in the HTML doc set. What this is indicating is that the visitor was at some point in an authenticated state when they subscribed for the e-mail, thus a custom visitor ID had been set.

This example is trying to do a lot, and builds on the narrative in the earlier texts. It is trying to show the non-retroactive nature of cross device ID stitching as well as the use of authentication as the key to stitching.